# Neo4j: Neo.ClientError.Cluster.NotALeader

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have installed [neo4j](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/neo4j) cluster on AWS EKS using [stable helm charts](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/neo4j)

```
helm install --name neo4j-stg stable/neo4j --set core.numberOfServers=3,readReplica.numberOfServers=3  --set neo4jPassword=**** --set acceptLicenseAgreement=yes
```

After that, list of pods launched for neo4j cluster-

```
# kubectl get pod
neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-0                     1/1     Running   0          70m
neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-1                     1/1     Running   0          70m
neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-2                     1/1     Running   0          70m
neo4j-stg-neo4j-replica-554bd99b98-7chx9   1/1     Running   0          70m
neo4j-stg-neo4j-replica-554bd99b98-gr7hp   1/1     Running   0          70m
neo4j-stg-neo4j-replica-554bd99b98-jh4dj   1/1     Running   0          70m
```

If we check the ROLE assigned to a pod-

```
# kubectl exec neo-helm-neo4j-core-0 -- bin/cypher-shell --format verbose \
"CALL dbms.cluster.overview() YIELD id, role RETURN id, role"
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                     | role           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| "3e162b58-7025-4cff-9908-a82a1739f7d7" | "LEADER"       |
| "6334fb74-3933-4c39-94e8-578545f13bc6" | "FOLLOWER"     |
| "1bc2e35b-fdde-48e4-ac1a-0f10bc6e5ff8" | "FOLLOWER"     |
| "795b92b2-7ebc-4981-8b1f-34c7b6c10e44" | "READ_REPLICA" |
| "736cb066-aac2-49fc-8a78-bda4b3d65de0" | "READ_REPLICA" |
| "9b5d0560-f620-40f5-9b05-d8109220dc2a" | "READ_REPLICA" |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

When we trying to write data into neo4j database, it throws an error-

```
Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::CypherError:   Cypher error:
  Neo.ClientError.Cluster.NotALeader: No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER
```

How neo4j service discover the "LEADER" pod?

```
# kubectl get svc neo4j-stg-neo4j -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
  ....
  ....
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 7474
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7474
  - name: bolt
    port: 7687
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7687
  selector:
    app: neo4j
    component: core
    release: neo4j
```

**How neo4j is ensuring write operations are only executed by "LEADER" pod.**

Answer (score 0):

Since the Helm chart is deploying neo4j core servers as a StatefulSet with a headless service, Kubernetes DNS create a DNS entry for the service that points at the internal IPs of the Pods, e.g.:

```
neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN  A   10.233.74.147
neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN  A   10.233.88.205
neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN  A   10.233.88.150
```

So, your client should be able to connect to the domain "neo4j" (which refers to the headless service) and figure out which server is the current leader.

Comment: A couple of queries-

1. will neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-0 be always a "LEADER"?
2. what if neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-0 crashed and will any of "FOLLOWER" become "LEADER"?
3. How kubernetes service for neo4j "neo4j-stg-neo4j" discover the leader? Will it search for 1st pod (in default) created  "neo4j-stg-neo4j-core-0" in stateFulSet?
4. Explanation of below shared error while write operation-
```
  Neo.ClientError.Cluster.NotALeader: No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER
```

Comment: Fair questions that made me think about my original answer. I have amended it.